# How to determine if a phonegap android activity is already running

Tags: android, cordova, android-activity

I have an android nfc reading application developed using phonegap. The application detects which mimetype was scaned and launches the app with the relevant file loaded.

```
if(receivedType.endsWith("/one")){
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html"); 
}else if(receivedType.endsWith("/two")){
   super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/other/index.html"); 
}
```

The problem is that on the first time of detecting mimetype "one" the app launches as desired, scan another tag with the same mimetype "one" then the app attempts to relaunch and crashes. I would like to detect if the app is already running and prevent the relaunch attempt.

Answer (score 1):

paste this on extend DroidGap and try to understand with logcat you may get answer

```
        public class CheckState extends DroidGap {

        static boolean active = false;

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            active = true;
            Log.i("Active onStart", active + "");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            active = false;
            Log.i("Active onStop", active + "");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);

            if (active == true) {
                super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
            } else {
                super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/other/index.html");
            }

        }
    }
```